# Align rotated text to the top right of image with CSS

Tags: css, rotation, transform, text-alignment

Struggling to top–align the text with the image, while also maintaining the same height. It's for a shopify page so seems i can only change the CSS. It's for a blog page where i'd like to have scrolling images (see attached).

[wireframe example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzYEw.jpg)

Code here...

```html
 <div>
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0473/3907/7794/files/AK01-1597-WB_1024x1024.jpg?v=1624265796"
              alt=""
              width="696"
              height="1045"/> 
    <p style="float:left;
              margin-left:-75px;
              display:inline-block;
              padding-top:0px;
              transform:rotate(90deg);
              transform-origin:100% 100%;
              -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
              -ms-transform-origin:100% 100%;
              -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
              -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;">
    <span>Side table by Peninsula, books by Uro Publications, local magazine Lindsay Magazine, carafe by Maison Balzac, handcream by Aesop.</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. https://jsfiddle.net/k6qtxjse/

```
div {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 696px;
  max-height: 1045px;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Adam! Is this possible to incorporate under only HTML?

Comment: Of course, just put it in style attributes, like you did with p element in your code example, although it's always better to put your styles in a CSS file.

Comment: By the way, you could also make the div `display: inline-block`, so that you don't need to set the image width and height to 100% and max-width/height to the image size. See what works better for you. https://jsfiddle.net/gLpt2u78/